# List Index Out of Range error, Python

Tags: python, list

I'm receiving a "list index out of range" error on some code I'm working on and can't figure out why. I've researched pretty extensively on this site already and it seems like the bulk of questions similar to mine have been easily solved by noting that Python list indexes start with 0.

Here's the code I'm working on -- to be upfront, I *don't* think the code works as intended right now, but I was simply checking to make sure if it made it through the loop initially. In other words, it'll be prettier later :)

```
ar = [5, 3, 4, 143, 43, 35, 2, 15, 23] 

def insertionSort(ar): 

    MasterList = []
    MasterList.append(ar)
    print len(MasterList[0])
    while len(MasterList[0]) > 1: 
        TemporaryList = MasterList[0]
        del MasterList[0] 
        p = TemporaryList[0]
        LessThanP = []
        GreaterThanP = []
        finallist = []
        for i in range(1, len(TemporaryList)):
            if TemporaryList[i] <= p: 
                LessThanP.append(TemporaryList[i])
            else: 
                GreaterThanP.append(TemporaryList[i])
        GreaterThanP.insert(0, [p])
        MasterList.insert(0, GreaterThanP)
        MasterList.insert(0, LessThanP)
        print (MasterList)

insertionSort(ar)
```

So, with the code as is, the length of MasterList[0] gets printed, but then the error pops up and it says that the index is out of range. I've tried including 'print' lines within the while loop to see if the code ever makes it through the loop once, but nothing prints, making me think that there's something happening before the loop's first iteration.

as always, your help is appreciated!

Comment: The error you get should show you which line triggered it.

Comment: The code does not produce any errors for me. Seems to be working.

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message? I can't seem to reproduce the error when I run your script.

Comment: Only error the code produces for me is because you print with parentheses once and without once.

Comment: Your code is pretty verbose for insertion sort. I recommend that you take a look at this implementation: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheInsertionSort.html

Comment: you are deleting `masterlist[0]` inside `while loop`.So when `masterlist` become empty, when `while loop` try next loop, `masterlist[0]` for empty `masterlist` .It shoudl give  `list index error`

Comment: hey folks! thanks for answering my question. 
I don't know why it wasn't working before, but when I compiled the code again and ran it, it didn't give me the error -- I'm sure it was a user error, but I *swear* it wasn't working 15 minutes ago, and I tried compiling it and running it *many* times. 

@BaraaH thanks for the link! I'm working on this problem to develop some algorithm skills so I don't want any unneeded outside help -- also, I'm still pretty new to coding algorithms, so that explains the verbosity! I'll be sure to check it out when I finish, though :)